# Changing redux state on component will unmount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to call an action and change the redux state on componentWillUnmount. I know calling apis are not safe in componentWillUnmount. But how safe is calling an action from componentWillUnmount? Will it execute 100% of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispatch an action in componentWillUnmount which would be handled by a corresponding reducer.
It will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% of the time to be precise. `componentWillUnmount` isn't supposed to be called when browser window is closed or the browser is terminated abnormally.

Besides these cases, its safe to `dispatch` actions in your `componentWillUnmount` for closing resources or whatever state change that you want.